# MongoDB .deleteOne not working in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So, i'm trying to delete a document when a button is pressed. The button code looks like this:

```
<form action="/patients/delete?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="patientID" name="patientID" value=' _id: <%= patient._id%>'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete this patient from the Database</button>
</form>
```

I've set up a route which looks like this:

```
router.delete('/delete', AuthControl.checkLoggedIn, patientsControl.patientDelete);
```

Which is calling this function in patientsControl:

```
    patientDelete = async (req, res) => {
    let DeleteParam = req.body.patientID;
    console.log(DeleteParam);
    let DeleteConfirm = await this.patientsModel.DeletePatient(DeleteParam);
    if (DeleteConfirm) {
        res.render('patients');
    } else {
        console.log("Error happening somewhere");
        }
    }
```

which is calling this function in the patientsModel:

```
async DeletePatient(DeleteParam) {
    return mongoose.connection.db.collection("PatientsDB").
    deleteOne({ _id : DeleteParam);
}
```

//EDIT: quickly fixed the above code, wasn't what I was running
Which is returning true, as I'm not logging an error in patientDelete above.

the console.log(DeleteParam); is returning the id for the document i'm trying to delete, like this:
`5f22dc43b1e72e9769263810`

and the document im trying to delete looks like this:

```
_id : 5f22dc43b1e72e9769263810
fName : "s"
lName : "s"
diseases : "s"
prescriptions : []
inhousedoctor : "s"
```

What confuses me is, that if i set the button value to <%= patient.fName %> instead, it deletes perfectly. Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: Ofc I mean that it works when i use fName instead like this:

````
        return mongoose.connection.db.collection("PatientsDB").
        deleteOne( {fName : DeleteParam});
    }```
````

Comment: Yea, just saw - wasn't returning an error, and it still isn't working :/

Comment: okay, for _id try this `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DeleteParam)` for _id like `deleteOne({ _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DeleteParam)});`

Comment: That one did it mate, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_id` of the document is of type `ObjectId` but you are searching for a *string*, so no documents match.

If you use a Mongoose model, the type is converted automatically. But here you are not actually using Mongoose other than as a way to get the underlying MongoDB connection (`mongoose.connection`). So you are then working with pure MongoDB which does *not* do the conversion for you.

So you can either use the corresponding Mongoose model and write e.g. `Patient.deleteOne({ _id: DeleteParam })` or just `Patient.findByIdAndDelete(DeleteParam)`, or you can continue using MongoDB directly but explicitly convert the value to an `ObjectId`, using `{ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DeleteParam) }`.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm running native mongodb inside the Mongoose connection as I'm having issues with the schemas. Isn't it possible to do this without having to define a schema, using just native mongo?

Comment: Yes, I described it at the end of my answer. The key is to convert the ID that you search for to an `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a contributing factor, but your form is a POST method but your endpoint is a DELETE. Maybe try making both either POST or DELETE.

Comment: I'm using method-Override, hence the weirdness in the methods haha